# Stuck in cardano node

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node

Running any cardano-cli command returns this error,Cardano-node is already running in another terminal,CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH is set in environment variable. Confirmed through echo. It leads to node.socket file white_check_mark eyes raised_hands
[image]

Comment: Did you update your terminal with `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Verify that your current user can read the socket file with `ls -l $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH`

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, verify that your current user can see the socket file with `ls -l $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH`

The error that you see will be due to either:

1. The node is not running (but you confirmed that it is running so not that)
2. Environment variable `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` is not set for the **current user** (but you confirmed that it has a value)
3. `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` having a value that is different to the actual path of the socket file

Most likely is option 3 which could be due to a typo when setting `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH`

Another possibilty is that the current user might not have permission to read the socket file, but the error normally states if there is a permissions issue so I don't think it's that in your case.